# Collapsible Grouped List Gallery View

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, custom-list, collapsible-sections

I have a SharePoint Online Modern list set with a grouped view.  When viewing it as a list, each group can be collapsed by clicking the small arrow.  When I change to gallery view, it is no longer possible to collapse.

Is there an alternate way to make a collapsible gallery view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group items in the item using JSON formatting as the example shown in this article: [Build custom group headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-gallery-formatting#build-custom-group-headers). However, there is no built-in way to create a collapsible gallery view in SharePoint Online. The gallery view does not support collapsing groups like the grouped view does. Maybe there are third-party solutions available that can add this functionality. You can search the SharePoint app store or consult with a SharePoint developer to find a solution that meets your needs.